# Transact-SQL ISJSON function doesn't accept scalars?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a column in MS-SQL 2016, which should be a valid JSON but doesn't necessary be a JSON Object or Array.

I tried to use the ISJSON function as a check-constraint, when I found out it doesn't work as expected. The documentation doesn't mention anything about scalar values or objects, so it should work for a quoted string, as it's a valid JSON value. I've tried with single quotes, escaping the quotes, etc. but nothing helps.

Using ISJSON on a scalar string:

```
SELECT ISJSON('"test"')   <--- result is 0
```

Strangely enough the following is accepted:

```
SELECT ISJSON('["test"]')   <--- result is 1
```

So the same scalar value is accepted as a JSON when put inside an array but isn't accepted on it's own. Is Microsoft not conforming to the JSON standard here?

Comment: `"test"` is not a valid JSON object value. So the result is correct.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here. Both queries *are* using a scalar value (a single literal string), and are working as expected. `'"test'"` is not valId JSON. if you try `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON('"test"');` you'll get an error: `JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 0.`. The fact that `ISJSON('"test"')` returns `0` further confirms this.

Comment: It is valid JSON but not according to SQL Server.

Comment: You can try writing your own... if the string does not start with `{` and `[` then wrap it inside `[` and check count of values inside the resulting array... should be one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Initial answer (July 2019):*

The site https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com says `"test"` is not a valid JSON according to [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) or [ECMA-404](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm), but is a valid JSON according to [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159). The latest version of the JSON specification is [RFC 8529](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), which says: "Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array."

It seems that SQL Server 2016 implemented the first JSON specification, because that's the one mentioned in the [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-escapes-special-characters-and-control-characters-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

*Later Edit (June 2022):*

In SQL Server 2022 the `ISJSON` function has a new optional parameter, where you can specify the type of JSON that is expected. If you specify `SCALAR` or `VALUE` in this parameter, you would get a `1` as the result.

The [updated ISJSON documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) says: *"The json_type_constraint value SCALAR can be used to test for IETF RFC 8259 conformant JSON document that contains only a JSON scalar value at top level. A JSON document that doesn't contain a JSON scalar value at top level conforms with IETF RFC 4627."*

The following table summarizes the result of the `ISJSON` function, with various parameters:

| JSONString | IsJSONDefault | IsJSONValue | IsJSONArray | IsJSONObject | IsJSONScalar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| ["test"] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| test | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| true | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| {"a": "b", "c": "d"} | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Thanks, that explains it, so Microsoft is conforming a standard, just an older one. I hope newer versions of MSSQL will support the new definition. They probably won't change ISJSON though for backward compatibility reasons, but I would be glad for a new function like ISJSON_VALUE or something.

Comment: @BlackGhost: indeed, the new version of SQL Server supports the new definition. I have updated by answer with more details.